# What is the benefit of using node.js http-errors package?

Tags: node.js, express

In multiple tutorials I saw people using [http-errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-errors) npm package. Based on its docs, it provides only a handful of functions. I do not understand its popularity and use-case.

Why not simply use

```
return res.status(errorCode).render(errorTemplate)
```

?

Does this package provide something useful, or is it literally just a custom one-function middleware? Its weekly downloads are astronomical.

Answer (score 0):

Strange question...

It should be a comment but write here du to the length...

First the download rate is due to the fact that it's a part of popular node.js frameworks... A visit on the github page will explain this :

> Create HTTP errors for Express, Koa, Connect, etc. with ease.

For the use case, just a visit inside the code shows what it does :

- Set and fill specific errors
- Fill the res with this errors

Nothing surprising, but it does well the job, and it's not usefull to reinvent the wheel...

https://github.com/jshttp/http-errors/blob/master/index.js